# MediaQuery fail to get width and height

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to building android application with Flutter. So,I was trying to get width and height of the screen and got this error.I try fixing this error from various source but still couldn't get it off

Why did this happened and how can i fix this ?

[main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9CK3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to suround MyApp() with the MaterialApp not put it inside the MyApp widget like this:

```
runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()))
```

and delete the material app inside MyApp() like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ...
    );
  }
```

hope it helped

Comment: it is now working ! thank you . but why it didn't work before ? i already warp my widget in MaterialApp and then inside Scaffold as seen in the picture .

Comment: i dont now i just messed around with the code in my flutter project

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to initialize those variables as global

static double screenWidth; 
static double screenHeight;

then assign those values under widget build method : 
screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
 
and for to make it clear if it is work try to print them.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaQuery.of(context)` tries to look up information from the `MediaQueryData` class in your Widget tree from *above* the widget you are using it in with the help of `context` passed.

In your case, the `MediaQueryData` (from `MaterialApp`) and `Container` share the same `context`, and thus it cannot find any.

You have two options:
1. Break the widget tree for the Scaffold to have a different context:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
...

class Home extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
...
```

2. Use the [Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) Widget:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context){
          return Scaffold(
...
```